# Prepend code into a function

Tags: c, grep

I have a function:

```
void srunner_free(SRunner *sr){
.......
}
```

I am looking to prepend some C code before the original function body, so it becomes:

```
void srunner_free(SRunner *sr){
//Some other random code, not necessary printfs, printf is just an example
printf("hello world");

.......
}
```

How do I go about doing this? can I do it with tools such as grep?

THanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You can do it with `awk`.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi There are lots of reasons one might want to do something like this. One reason that comes to mind is to be able to quickly add and remove extra calls for testing, code profiling, etc.

Comment: I am looking to inject custom code into the Check unit testing library for C, I am aware of the original source file, so I just make this change at runtime so some of my code is also run , this extra code is for recording results etc which the original library does not provide

Comment: I noticed that you're adding prints some of your `free` functions. Are you trying to debug a memory leak? If so, there are some good tools out there, and methods for tracking memory usage.. Just gotta let us know ;)

Comment: How, can you guide me to a better solution? I hate doing what I am trying to do :( I come from the Java world, where we don't tend to do this kind of stuff..

PS: the function in question is called externally, and I do not want to make changes to the Makefile which rules out using #DEFINE hacks and dynamic linking etc..

Comment: @kingkong Even if you modify the source code while running your program this won't make any difference at runtime. I just mention this since you said *"...make this change at runtime..."*.

Comment: @juan.facorro I'm not sure if this is what kingkong meant, but it *is* possible to modify the actual binary code in memory at runtime for reasons such as this. In fact, there are lots of automated unit test suites that do exactly that sort of thing. Although, it may be more work than kingkong had in mind. It's certainly *easier* to make the changes in source and then recompile.

Comment: I am sorry for confusing you guys, if there is an okey way to inject this code at RUNTIME then I can have a look at it, but it looks like injecting it in source will be the most straightforward way to go.. possibly less error prone..

Comment: if you want to debug memory leaks, maybe try looking into valgrind if you haven't already: http://valgrind.org/

Comment: @kingkong I'm not suggesting you do it at runtime, but as far as doing it at runtime being somehow more error prone, you might be surprised. Source code is notoriously difficult and messy to parse, especially without proper tools. Compiled code, on the other hand, is relatively more easy to parse (although "parse" is a bit of a misnomer in the latter context), due to the fact that you are simply traversing well-defined and consistently-formatted data structures. IMO that is much less error prone than parsing code, with all its arbitrary spacing, loose(r) syntax, etc.

Comment: Search for "source code instrumentation c"? Perhaps there is something already done. And instrumenting binaries is also done quite regularly. Matching function headers in C isn't impossible (start with a C grammar and the correct tools...), but...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [coccinelle](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/) for this. This is a tool specifically made to modify source code like that.

Playing very quickly, with the following test input

```
$ cat test.c

int foo(int i)
{
        return i+1;
}

void srunner_free(SRunner *sr)
{
        int i;
        foo(i);
        return;
}
```

and the following coccinelle script

```
$ cat test.cocci 
@@
typedef SRunner;
statement S;
identifier sr;
@@
void srunner_free(SRunner *sr)
{
        ...
+       printf("hello world");
        S
        ...
}
```

the result is

```
$ spatch -sp_file test.cocci test.c
init_defs_builtins: /usr/share/coccinelle/standard.h
HANDLING: test.c
diff = 
--- test.c      2014-03-08 01:34:13.000000000 +0100
+++ /tmp/cocci-output-24589-dfa2db-test.c       2014-03-08 01:34:57.000000000 +0100
@@ -7,7 +7,9 @@ int foo(int i)
 void srunner_free(SRunner *sr)
 {
        int i;
+       printf("hello world");
        foo(i);
+       printf("hello world");
        return;
 }

$
```

The printf statement here is put in front of every single statement which is not exactly what you want, but the result is not that far off. I am not sure how to restrict this right of the top of my head, but I think I have seen examples of this before, so it should be possible.

---

**Update:** I continued looking into this today, and it was relatively easy to modify what
I initially suggested to be exactly the solution wanted. The script now consists of two rules.

The first rule is just a matching rule, performing no modifications. It matches two adjacent statements and binds a position to the last one of those. So this rule will bind a 
position to all statements inside the function except the very first statement.

The second rule then inserts the printf statement (or whatever) in front of the first statement by excluding any of the statements bound by a position in rule1.

```
@rule1@
typedef SRunner;
statement S1, S2;
identifier sr;
position p;
@@
void srunner_free(SRunner *sr)
{
        ...
        S1
        S2@p
        ...
}

// typedefs are actually global, so no need to repeat
// (and doing so would in fact generate an error)
@rule2@
statement S;
identifier sr;
position p != rule1.p;
@@
void srunner_free(SRunner *sr)
{
        ...
+       printf("hello world");
        S@p
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this properly on every function, or a large number of functions, and want to do it properly, you will either need to alter the compiler, or build a lexical analyser (using, say `lex`) that uses the same rules as C, and outputs the extra lines.

If you want to bodge it up for a few functions, and are prepared for criteria like 'no macros, normal formatting etc', use a scripting language like `perl`, and regular expressions. This is, however, always going to be a bodge.

Comment: I want to use Macros, but I dont know how I Would use them, since the function is being called from outside itself.. Also, there will always ever be 1 instance of this function, hence the later method you mentioned is what I had in mind..